# Installing ckeditor (version5) on angular with ckeditor5-image

Tags: angular, svg, ckeditor5

I am trying to install ckEditor5 with ckeditor5-image but I get errors with angular 12. My package.json looks as below under dependencies

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^4.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^34.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^34.2.0",
```

My code is as below

ts file

```
public Editor = ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ AutoImage ],

    } )

editorData =
    `<p><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk">https://maps.google.co.uk</a></p>`;
```

html file

```
<ckeditor #editor
    [data]="editorData"
    [editor]="Editor"
    id="classic-editor"
    name="classic-editor">
</ckeditor>
```

The errors are about all svg files in node_modules

```
./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/theme/icons/return-arrow.svg:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

> 

I wonder if anyone can help?